# Identifying American-Style dates

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a program that will identify American Dates through a regular expression, and for some reason I keep picking up ALL dates not just american style dates. Can someone take a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong with the regex?

I have thoroughly looked through the re Python docs to craft an expression that will pick up any american style dates styled MM-DD-YYYY.

```
import shutil, os, re

date_pattern = re.compile(r"""^(.*?)
    ((0|1)?\d)-
    ((0|1|2|3)?\d)-
    ((19|20)\d\d)
    (.*?)$
    """, re.VERBOSE)

american_date_list = []
file_list = os.listdir('.\date_files')
for file in file_list:
    american_date = date_pattern.search(file)
    if american_date:
        american_date_list.append(file)
```

The below are my test files:

```
'02-25-1992 bermuda'
'21-07-1992 Utah'
'25-02-1992 atlanta'
'bahamas 12-15-1992'
```

My expectation would be that I would only get a match object for first and last listed file names, but I keep getting a match for every file name.

What am I doing wrong in the regular expression?

Comment: What do you plan to do with '02-09-1992' which is an acceptable format in both styles but has a much different meaning?

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong in the regular expression?

Using it.

Seriously. You should use regex only if there is no other reasonable option.

Python has a good standard library for working with dates and times, and that is not for your liking use libraries like arrow.

Instead of breaking your head on Regex do:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: datetime.datetime.strptime("1-12-2018", "%m-%d-%Y")
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 12, 0, 0)
```

This gets you have a legal date. Now, try an parse a non existing month:

```
In [20]: datetime.datetime.strptime("13-12-2018", "%m-%d-%Y")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-02e1071664f7> in <module>()
----> 1 datetime.datetime.strptime("13-12-2018", "%m-%d-%Y")

/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    563     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    564     format string."""
--> 565     tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    566     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    567     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    360     if not found:
    361         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 362                          (data_string, format))
    363     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    364         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data '13-12-2018' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y'
```

So you see this will throw an exception you can use in your code if the format isn't legal.

`strptime` can also handle special dates for you

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("02-29-2018", "%m-%d-%Y")  # throws 
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Answer (score -1):

In the second line you have the following matches:

- `^(.*?)` matches `'2`
- `((0|1)?\d)-` matches `1-`
- `((0|1|2|3)?\d)-`  matches `07-`
- `((19|20)\d\d)` matches `1992`
- `(.*?)$` matches `Utah'`

Put `\b` before `((0|1)?\d)` to ensure that it starts matching at a word boundary, so it won't match in the middle of a number.

```
^(.*?)\b((0|1)?\d)-((0|1|2|3)?\d)-((19|20)\d\d)(.*?)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/AgDzLU/1/)